# Oracle sql task, printing a vertical histogram according to a data

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I had a task, to write a procedure that prints a horizontal histogram, I have acomplished it, now I have to make the histogram to be printed vertical, I am working on this like 2 days nothings works, I am attaching the first version of the program below(horizontal histogram

`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_histogram (p_owner varchar, p_table varchar, p_col varchar) IS
    max_occur_sql varchar(200):= 'select max(count(*)) from '|| p_owner ||'.'|| p_table ||' group by '|| p_col;
    row_cnt_sql varchar(200):= 'select count(count(*)) from '|| p_owner ||'.'|| p_table ||' group by ' || p_col;
    max_colLen_sql varchar(200):= 'select max(length('||p_col||')) from '||p_owner||'.'||p_table;
    col_infoTable_sql varchar(200):='select '|| p_col ||' ,count(*)  from '|| p_owner ||'.'|| p_table || ' where '|| p_col ||' is not null group by '|| p_col || ' order by '|| p_col;
    max_colLen number(10);
    max_occur number(10);
    row_cnt number(10);
    command varchar2(1000);
    type cur_ref  is ref CURSOR;
    col_name varchar(200);
    col_freq number(10);
    ijj integer := 1;
    c_temp_table cur_ref;
    few_tooMany_error EXCEPTION;
begin
    execute immediate max_colLen_sql INTO max_colLen;
    execute immediate max_occur_sql INTO max_occur;
    execute immediate row_cnt_sql INTO row_cnt;
    if row_cnt >= 100 or row_cnt <= 0 then
        raise few_tooMany_error;
        return;
    end if;
    open c_temp_table for col_infoTable_sql;
    loop
        fetch c_temp_table into col_name,col_freq;
        exit when c_temp_table%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put( ijj || ':');
        ijj := ijj + 1;
        for i in 0..(col_freq / (max_occur/50)) loop
            dbms_output.put('*');
        end loop;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
    end loop;
    close c_temp_table;
exception   
    when few_tooMany_error then
        dbms_output.put_line('Few or too many distinct values in column');
    when others then 
        dbms_output.put_line('Non-existing table or column');
end;
/
set serveroutput on
CALL print_histogram('nikovits','customers','c ust_year_of_birth');
```

`
this is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkeVy.png)

and I need this output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYKMF.png)

I tried to get the values to one array, and then print it according to data, But it didnt work , please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can always render it yourself. For example:

```
with
p (maxv) as (select max(v) from t),
s (n) as (select p.maxv from p union all select n - 1 from s where n > 0)
select s.n, listagg(case when t.v >= s.n then '*' else '-' end)
  within group (order by t.y) as c
from t cross join s group by s.n order by s.n desc
```

Result:

```
  N    C      
  --   ----- 
  16   --*--  
  15   --*--  
  14   --*--  
  13   --*--  
  12   --*--  
  11   --*--  
  10   --*--  
  9    --*--  
  8    --*--  
  7    --*-*  
  6    --*-*  
  5    --*-*  
  4    --*-*  
  3    *-*-*  
  2    ***-*  
  1    ***-*  
  0    *****
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1BBn3pZl).